# Not able to show icon in Trent Richardson datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

Here is working example in [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uDVwx/). 
The icon shows only when I am using jQuery UI 1.8.18, if I am using the latest version which is jQuery UI 1.8.21, then the icon won't show up?

Is there a bug or am I missing something?

The Trent datetime picker documentation is [**here**](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).It says "In addition all datepicker options are still available through the timepicker addon."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error: $("#from-datetime").datetimepicker is not a function
Source File: http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
Line: 73

It's just a `datepicker`  not `datetimepicker`
Datetimepicker is another jquery plugin, may be it's not compatible with newest JUI

Working example
http://jsfiddle.net/uDVwx/3/

The point is you have to call in this order: jquery, jquery ui, jquery addons. But as I look at the console debug, there is an error with datetime picker addon and jquery ui 1.8.21

Comment: you could not open the jsFiddle file? It is working fine from my side? did you include the necessary files? Trent datetime picker is build based on jQuery UI date picker, should not have compatible issues.Thanks

Comment: oh, it works.So question is `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.js` is not same as `jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js?`

Comment: Can you post full page with jquery, juqry ui, and datetimepicker plugins?

Comment: OK, i post the link for the datetime picker i am using. Thanks. The included script files you can see from my jsFiddle.

Comment: Update the script, it's work but with some error. Next time you should try firebug to find out what happend

Comment: Yes I did care for the orders. I did not see the error in Firebug, would you mind showing me the error messages you've got? It works for `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.js`, but not `jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js`, why is that? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Timestamp: 7/10/2012 10:13:10 PM
Error: $.ui is undefined
Source File: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js
Line: 26