# Open datetimepicker with icon only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datetimepicker

I'm currently using [Trent Richardson's datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) in a project. It's linked to a textbox so that when you click in the textbox, the picker pops up and you can either select a time or manually type something in.

**My question:** How do I add an icon "inside" the textbox, or just at the edge of the textbox, so that you can click in the textbox *without opening the date/time picker*, or open the date/time picker with the icon, which will then populate the textbox with your choice? Thus you have your choice of manually entering a time without the picker coming up or just using the picker.

The bootstrap date/time picker has this feature, but I need to use jQuery and not bootstrap for this project.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415422/not-able-to-show-icon-in-trent-richardson-datetime-picker), which is similar, but launches the picker from *both* the icon and textbox.

Comment: I don't know if that answer can help ? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112035/open-jquery-datepicker-by-clicking-on-an-image-w-no-input-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated fiddle for the only icon datepicker show;

[**http://jsfiddle.net/uDVwx/33/**](http://jsfiddle.net/uDVwx/33/)

**Jquery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {

        $("#from-datetime").datetimepicker({
            showOn: 'both',
            buttonImage: 'http://testsite.shadownetwest.com/datepicker4/development-bundle/demos/images/calendar.gif',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        }) .click(function() {
      $("#ui-datepicker-div").hide();
    });

        $(".ui-datepicker-trigger ").click(function(){$("#ui-datepicker-div").show()});

    });

});
```

**HTML code**

```
<fieldset id="fieldset">
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="from-datetime">From: </label></dt>
        <dd><input type="text" value="" id="from-datetime" name="from-datetime"/></dd>
    </dl>

</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

Comment: is there a simple way to change the size of the buttonImage? Is there something like a `.ui-datepicker-icon` class that I can apply css to?

Comment: @lg22woo i think you can use class .ui-datepicker-trigger{} to set height and width of an icon

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind an onclick event on a button to the creation of the datepicker entity. For example,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myButton").click = initiate;
});

function initiate() {
    $("#datepickerarea").datepicker();
}
```

Have the button (or whatever you like) with `id="myButton"` and when its clicked, it'll spawn a new datepicker. If you want the button to be a toggle, you'll have to keep track of the datepicker state and then remove it if it's already there.

```
function initiatie() {
    if($("#filter_date").datepicker( "widget" ).is(":visible")) {
        $("#datepickerarea").datepicker("destroy");
    } else {
        $("#datepickerarea").datepicker();
    }
}
```

EDIT: The datepicker will not initialize until you TELL it to initialize. This code will stop the datepicker from starting, because we're binding an event, (specifically the `onclick` event) to start the creation of datepicker. If no one clicks the button, datepicker simply won't start

EDIT2: apologies, my memory of how datepicker works was a little silly. You should initialize datepicker as an INLINE element, by starting the creation on a div instead of the input box. i.e.

```
<div id="datepickerarea"></div>
<input type="text" id="myinputbox" />
```

and the JS

```
$("#datepickerarea").datepicker({ altField: "myinputbox"});
```

This brings up the datepicker as a more permanent element, and puts whatever the user selects into the input field.

Comment: That's fine for opening it with the icon, but how do I prevent it from opening on clicking the textbox?

Comment: @lg22woo Sorry I misinterpreted, I edited my answer to get more at what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - we're getting closer, but this is still not quite what I'm trying to do; the button now _creates_ the picker, but you still need to click on the textbox that it's tied to in order to open/close it. To clarify: I'd like only the button to open/close the picker, and the date/time that is selected to be output to the textbox.